# Call method inside a constructor

Tags: php, class, constructor, this, fatal-error

So my question is not that why, and when. So simply answere what to change to correct the code.

```
    class html {
    var $title;
    var $result;
    var $content;
    public function __construct(){
        $title = "Untitled";
        $content = "Content";
        $this->setup_me();
    }
    public function BLANK(){
        $title = "Untitled";
        $this->setup_me();
    }
public function add($string){
    $result = $string;
}
public function setup_me(){
    $result = "$title--$content";
}
public function show(){
    echo $result;
}
}
$new1 = new html();
$new2 = html::BLANK();

$new1->show();
$new2->show();
```

And this returns me

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/fcs.php on line 23
```

I found some question here, but noone of them recomended a practical solution, everywhere only explanation, no sollution.

So plese give me the simple correcrtion, becouse i think i did it right.

Comment: Maybe you should bother reading and understanding the explanations. Your code is mostly nonsense which cannot work.

Answer (score 1):

Here just a working version without comments ;)

```
class html
{
    public $title;
    public $result;
    public $content;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->title = "Untitled";
        $this->content = "Content";
        $this->setup_me();
    }

    public static function BLANK()
    {
        $html = new html();
        $html->content = '';
        $html->setup_me();

        return $html;
    }

    public function add($string)
    {
        $this->result = $string;
    }

    public function setup_me()
    {
        $this->result = "{$this->title}--{$this->content}";
    }

    public function show()
    {
        return $this->result;
    }
}

$new1 = new html();
$new2 = html::BLANK();

echo $new1->show()."\n";
echo $new2->show()."\n";
```

Comment: So that is great, but **BLANK** constructor returns the same as the **__constructor**. In my code it returns **__construct** (Untitled--Content) **BLANK** (Untitled--)

Comment: DONT WORK! this is not the answer

Comment: Ah ok, I see your problem, but you cannot have two constructors. There is always just one and it is called when you create an instance of the object. Because in your code, you want to set the default values of title and content in the constructor, you have to set the content of content to an empty string in the static BLANK methof and call setup_me again. let me update the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just instantiate $new2 as an html object.

```
$new1 = new html();
$new2 = new html();

$new2->BLANK();

$new1->show();
$new2->show();
```

Comment: Just try to debug it. It even dont return a character. Dont work

Comment: it is not answere to my question!